# When setState call from parent component then child component doesn't work with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use `Menu` component with Menu events. So I created `MenuEvents` component.
The `MenuEvents` component renders `Menu` component as a child component.

The `Menu` component has `MenuItem` components as children.If `MenuItem`'s `parent` props is `tru`e then user should create sub MenuItems.

MenuItem's dropdown works when user clicked.

When `MenuEvent` components state change with `setState` then `MenuItem` components dropdown doesn't open.

So I assume that when parent component state change then it will re render and so when re render `MenuItem` component doesn't work well.

Here is the what is happening:

1. When click the parent `MenuItem` dropdown open,
2. then it call `handleSelect` `MenuEvents`'s event.
3. `handleSelect` event change the `MenuEvents` state
4. `Menu` and `MenuItem` components re render
5. So dropdown can't be shown by user.

Here is implementation source:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";

export default class MenuEvents extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logs: []
    };
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    this.renderLogs = this.renderLogs.bind(this);
  }
  handleSelect(e) {
    const logs = this.state.logs.slice();
    logs.unshift(`text: ${e.text}`);
    this.setState({ logs });
  }

  renderLogs = () => {
    return this.state.logs.map((log, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{log}</li>;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Menu onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
          <MenuItem text="Home" />
          <MenuItem text="Products" />
          <MenuItem text="About" parent>
            <MenuItem text="Team" />
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <p>Event Logs</p>
        <ul>{this.renderLogs()}</ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is full implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-field-nxt7l

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: where did you send state to menu item as props?

Comment: This is not even valid `id:${e.itemId}  text: ${e.item.props.text}` syntax.

Comment: What library does `Menu` come from?

Comment: @ArupRakshit it is came from Menu onSelect event. it is valid.

Comment: @charlietfl it is only demonstrate.You can try also ul and li.

Comment: @HDM91 I couldnt send state

Comment: you can send state as props to child component so when the parent component state changes and re render , the updated state would send to its childs

Comment: did you use rc-menu ?

Comment: @HDM91 No I created of mine. But it is demo for clarify the problem. parent prop is always is true.It is not need to send as prop.

Comment: Why I asked is those event properties don't make sense for typical event object. Creating  a runnable sandbox version would be helpful

Comment: @charlietfl I edited question.Please look at.